# LTSpice: Not measuring expected value

Tags: ltspice

The below is the circuit in question using LTSpice XVII(x64) (17.0.21.0)

[image]

The two sources have the exact same sine wave, just with different DC offsets. One with a DC offset of 5V, the other with 0V.

So, when you subtract, or measure the voltage between Vcc and Vref, you should get a perfect DC value. And we do. But, when you measure the voltage between Vdiv and Vref, it has some AC signal.

I'm going to assume there is a setting or a way LTspice functions that I don't know about.

Here is the output measuring the voltage between Vcc and Vref. A perfect 5V DC
[image]

Here is the output measuring the voltage between Vdiv and Vref.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known problem that's been haunting LTspice XVII since a year or so. It gets even worse, just try making `R1` to be `1`, then plot the same differential voltage. Adding `.opt plotwinsize=0` makes no difference.

The solutions are:

- impose a small timestep, but it can get very small and the effects seem to be linearly decreasing
- add `.opt method=gear` for LTspice XVII from 2020 and beyond
- use the version of LTspice XVII from `May 6 2019` or before (as it appears in the `Help > About`)
- use the discontinued LTspice IV.